# Get access to an account of someone living abroad

Tags: united-states, banking

My brother opened a bank account a couple of year ago in Utah , now he lives abroad and wants to get the money out. He does not have an online banking or a current debit card, only an expired one, but does not remember the pin. What kind I do from a legal perspective to act on his behalf and withdraw the money

Comment: Does he have checks? How would he get his money if he were still in Utah?

Comment: He has an expired debit card but does not remember the pin , but no checks

Comment: The obvious answer is to go to the bank (or ask your brother to phone them) and ask what they need.

Answer (score 2):

Most banks will do business with you by telephone, and would issue a debit card with a new PIN, or checks, which would be mailed to a new address if they received a request telephone from the account holder, so long as the account holder authenticated himself with mother's maiden name, social security number, the account number, the branch where the account was opened, and similar information. Often, telephone service is available even during hours when the bank's branch offices are not open.

If it is necessary to do business in person, he could prepare a notarized power of attorney and provide it to someone who could go in person to the bank and make a withdrawal, but that would probably be a second best solution.